# "adb pull" stuck in half way

Tags: android, mobile, adb

Suddenly my "adb pull" command will stuck in the middle of the process.
I'm not sure what cause it, after install some application or driver.
Happens for Pull one files or multiple files.

Does anyone encounter the same issue before? thanks.

Example:

> U:\batch>adb pull /sdcard/xxxlog/mobilelog .\xxxlog\
>
> [ 94%] /sdcard/xxxlog/mobilelog/APLog_xxx/main_log_1__xxx: 87%

[Here a screenshot from my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlgCI.png)

Comment: I changed another device and the problem is so solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for my specific answer, and provide a possible answer to who encounter similar problem.

after I reinstall the whole os, testing different adb version,
the issue still remains.

during testing adb version,
I found the issue will not happens if i use **Local Disk**...
where issue happens when using **Network Drive**..

So a possible solution, is **don't use Network drive**

Comment: +1 Thanks. This happened to me when I connected to the device from a Ubuntu guest machine inside a VirtualBox, and I was trying to `adb pull` a large file to a VirtualBox Shared Folder (on my host OS). Pulling to a folder local to the guest OS worked more reliably, however I still had trouble pulling multi-gigabyte files. To eventually get big files across, I used a (somewhat adapted) version of the [`adb_repull.py`](https://gist.github.com/alopatindev/e94ff95ea834500abe2da81ac2a7764f) script I found in [this answer on Android Enthusiasts SE](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/202737/18559)

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this problem while copying files from My Ubuntu machine to my Pixel 7.

A workaround based on [this bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36920010#comment30), is to run

`adb shell exit`

in another terminal whenever it gets stuck until all files are copied. You can also run

`watch -n 30 adb shell exit`

to run the command every 30 seconds so you don't have to keep watching the process. I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

Every time I encounter this, it ends up being a max path length issue. Open a shell on the device using adb and review the file names within the directories that you are pulling. If any have exceedingly long names, they will silently fail and adb will hang

The thing that really throws you for a loop is that it usually fails after giving a percentage complete which makes you think it's a faulty connection or some other issue.

I haven't found a good way to recursively list out file names in shell and test their name length prior to doing the pull in order to know that the issue is going to happen, but when I have the same issue and rename long files, it ends up working on the next attempt.

Comment: Nope. For relatively bigger file name it is working

Answer (score 1):

I encountered similar problem on adb server (v 1.0.40) started on Windows 7 machine. When tried to pull files from device on other machine running Linux in same local network (I used: "adb -H  pull ...") the adb was freezing occasionally.

The solution was to not use Windows for ADB server.

This problem was NOT visible, when adb server was running on Linux VM (Ubuntu 16.4/ VirtualBox). Hope that this helps.

BR,
Ziggy

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem when trying to transfer a large amount of data from an Android phone to a Raspberry Pi 3B+, and the `logcat` output seemed to reveal that adb was silently failing due to an issue with USB buffer reads (unfortunately, I don't have the exact message with me).

After the initial failure, it was possible to get another few files individually by unplugging the phone, running `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server`, and plugging it back in between each one, but the only longer-term fix I could find was restarting the Raspberry Pi. This solution, however, is not permanent, and must be repeated occasionally.

I was not able to replicate this issue on Windows or on a traditional Ubuntu system.

Answer (score 0):

In my case `adb` started to hang when it tried to `push` / `pull` folders / files with white spaces in it. Try replacing:

```
adb push input path output path
```

with

```
adb push "input path" "output path"
```

If you use `adb` in you code (e.g. `nodeJS`) and above doesn't help, you can try encoding your paths like so:

```
"output path".replaceAll(" ", "\\ ")
```

You may also want to escape `\\"` e.g. this:

```
execSync(`adb push "${inputPath}" "${outputPath}"`);
```

would become:

```
execSync(`adb push \\"${inputPath}\\" \\"${outputPath}\\"`);
```

So the full example would be:

```
execSync(`adb push \\"${inputPath.replaceAll(" ", "\\ ")}\\" \\"${outputPath.replaceAll(" ", "\\ ")}\\"`);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same thing, and it ended up just being an issue with the progress bar. At least in my case.

The pull was still progressing, as I could tell by checking the file count in the target directory. The progress bar would freeze, but the transfer finished just fine. In my case there were windows, no any whitespaces in the path.